# Configure tomcat on windows, where is the configuration stored

Tags: tomcat

I have made some changes in the GUI "Configure tomcat" on windows but I cannot find where this has been written. Surely not to `bin\catalina.bat` and based on the change date-time I cannot find a single file in the tomcat directory that would correspond to such a change (except of course the logs). So where is this configuration?

Answer (score 2):

The application you use to configure Tomcat's Windows service is actually `prunmgr` from the [Procrun](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/procrun.html) suite. It is usually installed in `$CATALINA_HOME/bin` under a name like `tomcat8w.exe`. This is a 32 bits executable.

It's companion `prunsrv` is usually named like `tomcat8.exe` and is used to start the server. It doesn't use any of the `*.bat` scripts to do it. It is a 32 or 64 bit executable.

As most Windows application, `prunmgr` and `prunsrv` keep their configuration in the Windows registry, specifically in:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\<service name>
```

on 64 bit Windows or

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\<service name>
```

on 32 bit Windows, where `<service name>` is the name used to register the Windows service (e.g. `Tomcat8`). As usual, you can access the register with `regedt32.exe`, but it is better to use `prunmgr` to change it.